# what kind of display technology is this?

Tags: display

There is some kind of backlit display in the product markets which is most likely displaying behind the plastic. I don't know if this is related to LCD or electronic technology or maybe some kind of special plastic. I spent some time on the web to figure it out and finding wooden clocks that display numbers from the back of the veneer sheet but this is a different technology I think.
Does anyone know the name of this kind of display or any useful information about it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is almost certainly just very thin plastic with an LED behind it.

There is a technique called "double-shot injection moulding" for making plastic parts which are opaque in some areas and transparent in others. This will produce transparent regions that function like light pipes.